# Identify this game questions based solely on music

Tags: discussion, game-identification

Is it valid to ask for identification of a game just from a piece of music? A certain level of detailed information is clearly required for a good identify question. However, virtually all of us at some point have heard a piece of videogame music out of context somewhere like a Youtube video that we've recognised, but couldn't remember the game source. This'd make a great place to ask for music IDs, but if we can't provide any info other than the track it technically might not meet criteria for a question.

Personally I don't see a problem if the excerpt is long enough for a good ID, but I've never seen an identify-this-music question and wondered what other viewpoints might be on this..

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as someone who has had an interest in game music for over a decade, I could see where this could come in handy.

Heck, maybe we could even pull in new users for this kind of question.  I could even use [my own pulpit](http://www.vgmusic.com/) to advertise/suggest this.

Answer (score 3):

I see absolutely no problem with this, and indeed I've asked a couple of these myself. [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/what-is-this-sound-from), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/where-does-the-illusion-world-song-from-chocobo-racing-come-from).

Such an ITG would actually be above average in terms of quality, as it would not be based on possibly-erroneous data based on somebody's nebulous recalling (such as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/cold-themed-top-down-shooter-game-with-constant-freezing-damage)), but on actual and honest-to-goodness *facts*. We had no problem with accepting [an ITG question based on a screenshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37105/whats-the-name-of-this-nes-game-screenshot-provided), after all.

Answer (score -4):

We are not Shazam. Please do not try to use us as Shazam.

It is demeaning. :(

Comment: Shazam doesn't have game music.

Comment: 1. Shazam requires you to have a specific kind of device to use it (because there is no PC version). 2. Does Shazam even have game music in it?

Comment: I just used Shazam to ID the Mario Bros theme, but perhaps that is too easy an example. Anyway, my point is that I find ITG on the whole distasteful, and I don't think that this is any less distasteful.

Comment: Given that ITGs are allowed, the question is whether this subset of them should be allowed as well.  General distastefulness and wanted-offtopicness of ITGs can be discussed elsewhere :P